# TextView position in a RelativeLayout with background image

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

Good morning,

I try to explain my scenario:
there is an Activity with a background image representing a person who is speaking. I have to place my TextView exactly over the callout, so it seems that the person is speaking.
Below of the TextView I have to put two buttons that allow to go to the previous message or to the main menu.
How can I do this with a RelativeLayout?
What happens when the activity is displayed by a device with a screen resolution different from the one that I used to debug the application?

Thanks,
Nicola

Comment: can you post what you have done so far? You have to set the relativelayout at runtime based on the screen resolution of the device.

Answer (score 0):

simply use `android:layout_alignLeft="@id/yourtextID` and `android:layout_alignRight="@id/yourTextID` for your left and right Button that you are using.
I wrote an example that I think may help you:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rlText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Something that he said .." />
</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/rlText" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bRight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Right" />
</LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/rlText" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bLeft"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Left" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

**Simply use this To Set BackGround Image to your relative Layout**

```
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.Your_ID);
int resid=R.drawable.your_background_image;
layout.setBackgroundResource(resid);
```

**For TextView Position use:** `android:layout_gravity,android:gravity`

i hope this will help you...